# Creating links to a mobile app

Tags: url, mobile, deep-linking

Is there a way to create a general url that links to a mobile app? For example, is it possible to create a redirect uri that opens up a mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

You are interested in [iOS Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/) and [Android app links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/). If you do not have a website you can also look into doing this with [URI schemes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/communicating_with_other_apps_using_custom_urls). The quickest solution is to use [Branch](http://docs.branch.io) which bundles both together into one link.